# Failed to create/setup connection: ORA-01017 because setenv.sh environment variable has line break

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, environment-variables, application.properties, setenv

I'm getting this error in my Spring Boot Data JPA application:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:385) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:938) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:476) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:412) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:821) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:596) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:711) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:558) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
```

My application.properties has these properties:

```
spring.datasource.username=${NOTIF_USU}
spring.datasource.password=${NOTIF_PASS}
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG
```

And my setenv.sh looks like this:

```
export NOTIF_USU="stack"
export NOTIF_PASS="overflow"
```

What I get in the log is:

```
2019-11-28 17:28:47.900 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - configuration:
2019-11-28 17:28:47.900 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : allowPoolSuspension.............false
2019-11-28 17:28:47.900 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : autoCommit......................true
2019-11-28 17:28:47.900 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : catalog.........................none
2019-11-28 17:28:47.900 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionInitSql...............none
2019-11-28 17:28:47.900 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTestQuery.............none
2019-11-28 17:28:47.900 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTimeout...............30000
2019-11-28 17:28:47.900 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSource......................none
2019-11-28 17:28:47.900 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceClassName.............none
2019-11-28 17:28:47.900 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceJNDI..................none
2019-11-28 17:28:47.900 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
2019-11-28 17:28:47.900 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : driverClassName................."oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckProperties...........{}
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckRegistry.............none
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : idleTimeout.....................600000
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : initializationFailTimeout.......1
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : isolateInternalQueries..........false
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:oracle:thin:@99.99.99.99:1521:STACKOVERFLOW
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : leakDetectionThreshold..........0
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maxLifetime.....................1800000
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maximumPoolSize.................10
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricRegistry..................none
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricsTrackerFactory...........none
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : minimumIdle.....................10
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : password........................<masked>
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : readOnly........................false
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : registerMbeans..................false
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : scheduledExecutor...............none
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : schema..........................none
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : threadFactory...................internal
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : transactionIsolation............default
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : username........................"stack
"
2019-11-28 17:28:47.901 DEBUG 81456 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : validationTimeout...............5000
```

Notice that second to last line has a line break. When I run this without using environment variables, everything is the same except for that line:

```
2019-11-28 17:30:46.947 DEBUG 81536 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : transactionIsolation............default
2019-11-28 17:30:46.947 DEBUG 81536 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : username........................"stack"
2019-11-28 17:30:46.947 DEBUG 81536 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : validationTimeout...............5000
```

If I print the environment variables with CommandLineRunner, but adding "xxx" to the String of env.getProperty("NOTIF_USU") and env.getProperty("NOTIF_PASS"), I get:

```
2019-11-29 10:40:41.226  INFO 84308 --- [ost-startStop-1] p.c.s.n.NotificacionesApplication        : stack
xxx
2019-11-29 10:40:41.226  INFO 84308 --- [ost-startStop-1] p.c.s.n.NotificacionesApplication        : overflow
xxx
```

This clearly shows that setenv.sh is adding a line break to my environment variables values. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems a bug in Oracle JDBC Driver.

I changed the [Oracle Database 19c (19.3)](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc8/19.3.0.0/jar) drivers to [Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2.0.1)](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-ucp-122-downloads.html) and it worked.

Hope it helps